# Building Github plugin for Gerrit

Tags: maven, plugins, github, gerrit

I am trying to build the github plugin for Gerrit but I am getting maven errors.

The instructions say:

```
$ git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/github 
$ cd github
$ mvn install
```

I did that and then maven threw up the following errors(and then some):

```
 [ERROR] /home/lively/github/github-plugin/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/github/git/PullRequestCreateChange.java:[34,36] cannot find symbol
   symbol:   class BatchUpdate
   location: package com.google.gerrit.server.git
 [ERROR] /home/lively/github/github-plugin/src/main/java/com/googlesource/gerrit/plugins/github/git/PullRequestCreateChange.java:[36,36] cannot find symbol
   symbol:   class UpdateException
   location: package com.google.gerrit.server.git
```

The plugin requires the github-api which I built successfully.  I am not sure what is missing and I'm stymied.

Comment: Not sure, why you're building the github-api on your own. Do you really need it for Gerrit 2.12? _master_ (pointing to the 2.12 API) also fails for me, too, as well as on [gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com](https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/job/plugin-github-mvn-master/30/) _stable.2-11_  works.

Comment: It's to get the github-api working.  I had a wonky install and managed to get it installed.

Comment: @StephenKing where is the pre-built .jar?

Comment: @MongoTheGeek glad you got it working, care to share how you resolved?

Comment: @zzzeek here https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.12/job/plugin-github-mvn-stable-2.12/

Comment: @StephenKing wow, I am googling around and digging everywhere to see how that link is knowable (to no avail).   thanks!

Comment: @zzzeek you might have to follow the Gerrit [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repo-discuss/C33w5LJP5Mg/Io3n_8qSAgAJ) to know that. It's not an official service, but one by a very active community member.